# Get an array of duplicate array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where I'm testing for duplicate values. I want to get an array of only the duplicate values, to give an error message to the user, noting which are the offending values. I tried

```
$duplicates = array_diff( $array_with_dupes, array_unique($array_with_dupes) );
```

But that didn't return the only the duplicate values -- instead I got an empty array.

What's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$arr = array('a','a','b','c','d','d','e');
$arr_unique = array_unique($arr);
$arr_duplicates = array_diff_assoc($arr, $arr_unique);
print_r($arr_duplicates);
```

The above will return

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [5] => d
)
```

Answer (score 4):

An answer is [here](http://magp.ie/2011/02/02/find-duplicates-in-an-array-with-php/) ( Use `array_diff_assoc` instead of `array_diff`):

```
array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $array, array_unique( $array ) ) );
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question and fully comprehending what the OP was *actually* trying to accomplish :)

Comment: Thanks, rdlowrey, but I am the OP :) Feel free to rescind your upvote -- I found this answer shortly after I posed the question :P

Answer (score -2):

Use [array_intersect](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php);

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4);

$b = array(2,3);

var_dump(
    array_intersect($a,$b)
    );
//Outputs 2,3 as expected.
?>
```

Comment: OP has _one_ array and he wants to find all entries that appear twice in that array. Intersect finds all entries that appear in the both of _two_ arrays.